# C# Detecting null characters in a string array

Tags: c#, arrays, streamreader

I am reading in from a text file using `StreamReader` into a string array `text[]`. One of the lines in the textfile is being read in as `"\0"` in positions 1 -> 20 of the array. How would I go about detecting this null character and ignoring this line.

Code example:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Convert.ToString(openFileDialog1.FileName));
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    string l= sr.ReadLine();
    string[] parsedLine = l.Split(new char[] { '=' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    // Not working:
    if (parsedLine.Length == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ignoring line");
    }
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Could you not just do `if(l.contains("/0"){l.replace("/0","");}`

Comment: What is `line` doing there you haven't defined it anywhere is it `l` ??

Comment: sorry. `line` should have been `l`. typo.

Comment: @Duane. This does not work as `'\0` is seen as a null character, not a  series of character "\0"

Comment: @L337BEAN Yep, wasn't 100% sure so didn't post it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean a character with ascii code: 0

```
   if (parsedLine.Length == 0 || parsedLine[0] == '\0')continue;
```

**edit**
the above will work if parsedLine is a string, but for the parsing in your code:

```
    string[] parsedLine = l.Split(new char[] { '=' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                      .Where(s=>s.Length != 1 || s[0] != '\0').ToArray();
```

Comment: Does not work. Operator "==" cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'char'

Comment: @L337BEAN Oops, sorry, didn't read correctly, thought parsedLine was a read in string, added a linq alternative for the string array.

Comment: This is working to a certain extent. The problem now is that It is removing everything from the string each time. For example if `l` contains `H/0e/0l/0l/0o/0` after your line of code its passing l to parsedLine as `""`. I would like to keep the `hello`

Comment: hmm, this may be due to a space in the logfile. Ill check on it.

Comment: The logfile is riddles with null characters. The programs is picking up spaces as them and saving them null characters. Only way I can see to get around this is to check if the first character of l is null and the second character is `=`

Comment: @L337BEAN So it's more a matter of removing all occurences of \0 than to remove entries where only a \0 is entered? In that case you could use  l = l.Replace("\0", " ") to replace with spaces or l = l.Replace("\0", ""); to remove them altogether. Would that be viable?

Comment: Well I want to remove empty lines ( which I can do ), and lines thats first character is `\0` and second character `=`. These are being used as breaks in the logfile. eg: `= = = = = = = =` is being read as `=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0`

Comment: @L337BEAN For that example, the 2nd code sample should work, but I think the replace mentioned before still is easiest: string l= sr.ReadLine().Replace("\0","");   For the last example that would create a lot of empty elements after the split, but they would be removed with the RemoveEmtpyEntries clause. If the replace is not a viable solution, could you post (or upload) a longer sample file with the different scenarios?

Comment: The trouble is that `line.Replace("\0", "");` is not working. printing the string after running this still shows the `\0` as spaces.

Comment: Wait. I believe im using it wrong.

Update: yes, your correct. this is working.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in [`String.IsNullOrEmpty()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) method:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(l))
{
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: The line to ignore can contain other characters.

Comment: @brunocondeq - What characters would those be?  Based on the MSDN documentation it would ignore a null character and an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Just ignore the line if it contains the null character.

```
string l = sr.ReadLine();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(l) || l[0] == '\0'))
   continue;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a linq solution that should work:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Convert.ToString(openFileDialog1.FileName));
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    string l= sr.ReadLine();
    bool nullPresent = l.ToCharArray().Any(x => x.CompareTo('\0') == 0);

    if (nullPresent)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ignoring line");
    }
    else
    {
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string l= sr.ReadLine();
if (l == "") {
  MessageBox.Show("Ignoring line");
  continue;
}
```

Comment: The line to ignore can contain other characters.

Comment: This is not working. `string does not contain a definition for 'isEmpty'` Am I missing an assembly reference or something ?

Comment: He probably means `string.IsNullOrEmpty("string")`

Comment: @L337BEAN I missed, in C#, `l == ""` is ok for testing empty string.